# Inserting data using Phalcon and relationships

Tags: php, relationship, phalcon

I have just started to look at using the Phalcon framework. I've never really used a framework before (or really MVC for that matter) so it's a bit of a learning curve.

I have created 2 tables: `User` and `Client`.

A client can have many `User`'s, however a user can only have 1 `Client`.

I have the following Models:

```
<?php
class User extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $email;
  public $username;
  public $password;
  public $active;
  public $isAdmin; 
  public $client;

  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->setConnectionService('gateway-db');
    $this->belongsTo("clientId", "Client", "id");
  }
}

<?php
class Client extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
  public $id;
  public $code;
  public $name;
  public $active;

  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->setConnectionService('gateway-db');
    $this->hasMany("id", "User", "clientId");
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a new `User` that is linked to an existing `Client` with the following code, however the clientId field is `NULL` and not linked.

```
$client = Client::findFirstByCode("DEM");  

$user = new User();
$user->email = "lock@lock.com";
$user->is_admin = 1;
$user->username = "lock";
$user->active = 1;
$user->name = "Lachlan";
$user->password = $this->security->hash("password");
$user->client = $client;
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Field clintId is not present. You need to use `$this->belongsTo("id", "Client", "id");`. Same goes for the Client Model.

Note: Your field `client` is probably a integer, so it can't contain the whole `$client` object.

Try to assign the id: `$user->client = $client->id`.

Also think about using protected vars and getter/setter.